# How to run a python script in the background?

Tags: python, windows, backgrounding

I have a script that checks something on my PC every 5 minutes and I don't want Python to show on my task tray. I use Windows as my operating system.

Is there any way to make Python run in the background and force it to not show in my task tray?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Look for Schedule Tasks in the control panel.

Comment: at will pop up my script every X time (or it does'nt ?)
I thought about at, but im looking for another way

thanks

Comment: Task scheduler doesn't allow one to run tasks less than every minute (in case that's of concern)

Comment: Question asks for background, but Task Scheduler runs in foreground by default.

Answer (score 60):

If you run a console script using `pythonw.exe`, it will neither display a window nor appear in the task bar.  For example, I use the following command to launch [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) on startup:

```
C:\BenBlank\Python2.6\pythonw.exe scripts/ntlmaps
```

Be aware, however, that there is no way to interact with the script, nor to terminate it save via the Task Manager.

Comment: This is the best way I've found to run Python applications that use GUI (e.g. with Tkinter).

Comment: Wow, after a decade, this is still the best! Thanks

Comment: in Windows 10 task manager on the Users task a task called 'python' should be there which you can select and then click the  'End task' button

Answer (score 5):

Just another option you have:

You can create a shortcut to your Python script, then `right-click the shortcut --> Properties --> Shortcut tab`

There is a drop-down box under the Run option which lets you **run the command minimized.**

Comment: The program will still be visible in the taskbar and I think OP didn't want that

Answer (score 3):

You could run it as a service. See [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551780/)

Answer (score 2):

cron it on linux; schedule it on windows [control panel > scheduled tasks > Add scheduled task]

Comment: Windows scheduler runs it in the foreground; question asks for background. Also, in some versions of windows (e.g. Windows 7) it's under control panel -> administrative tools.

Answer (score 0):

To Run python file from any where :

Step 1:

```
Create Shortcut of Python File.
```

Step 2:

```
Place Shortcut in this location  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Step 3:

```
Now Right Click --> Go to Properties --> Shortcut --> Press any key on keyboard it will take one shortcut key
```

Step 4:

```
Now , Type the Shortcut key which you entered in previous step.
```

Step 5:

```
Check out Output!   :)
```