# Run python script in background

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, console

I have a python script that's run in the systray (WINDOWS), but when I use the pyinstaller2.0, it opens in systray, but also opens my console. 
This script doesn't involve graphics, but I need it to run in background and preferably not open the console.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can run it as a windows service. You would need to read the docs on how to do that though.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I read the documentation about this, but don't understand the implementation. but I trying again!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783531/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background